# Please, can anyone give me the exact source of ṛte jñānānna muktih?

Tags: identification-request

Please, can you give me the exact source of ṛte jñānānna muktih (ऋते ज्ञानान्न मुक्तिः)?

Comment: Searched in Digital Corpus of Sanskrit, but couldn't find. http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=dictionary&limit=20&first_letter=j&text_id=0&limit=20&page=132

Comment: @TheDestroyer If you will search mukti you will [find it](http://kjc-sv013.kjc.uni-heidelberg.de/dcs/index.php?contents=texte&PhraseID=73898).

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani I searched mukti too but didn't find it.  You are good at searching verses.

Answer (score 5):

I am posting this answer because TheDestroyer wanted me to post it.
This verse is present in **Caturbhuja Misra's Mugdhavabodhini** (commentary) of **Govindbhagavatpada Rasahrdaya Tantra**.

Rasa Hridaya Tantra is [believed](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/bvparishat/VXYiAc6hW9M/8wF0j0WaMwAJ) to be a work of [Govinda Bhagavatpada](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Govinda_Bhagavatpada), although some details of work are contested.

Rasahrdaya Tantra's [15th verse](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/6_sastra/7_ayur/grasht_u.htm):

> स्थिरदेहोऽभ्यासवशात्प्राप्य ज्ञानं गुणाष्टकोपेतम् / प्राप्नोति
>   ब्रह्मपदं न पुनर्भवावासदुःखेन //
>
> sthiradeho'bhyāsavaśātprāpya jñānaṃ guṇāṣṭakopetam / prāpnoti
>   brahmapadaṃ na punarbhavāvāsaduḥkhena // GRht_1.15 //

Commentary:

> अधुना स्थिरदेहस्य फलं व्यनक्ति स्थिरेत्यादि  
>   adhunā sthiradehasya
>   phalaṃ vyanakti sthiretyādi // GRhtCM_1.15:1 //
>
> पूर्वोक्तस्यैव रसराजस्याभ्यासात् सेवनाद्धेतोः स्थिरदेहः पुमान्
>   ब्रह्मपदं प्राप्नोति  
>   pūrvoktasyaiva rasarājasyābhyāsāt
>   sevanāddhetoḥ sthiradehaḥ pumān brahmapadaṃ prāpnoti // GRhtCM_1.15:2
>   //
>
> ब्रह्मपदं परमानन्दस्वरूपम् 
>    brahmapadaṃ paramānandasvarūpam //
>   GRhtCM_1.15:3 //
>
> किंकृत्वा ज्ञानं प्राप्य 
>   kiṃkṛtvā jñānaṃ prāpya // GRhtCM_1.15:4
>   //
>
> कीदृशं ज्ञानं गुणाष्टकोपेतम् अणिमाद्यष्टसिद्ध्युपेतम्
>    kīdṛśaṃ
>   jñānaṃ guṇāṣṭakopetam aṇimādyaṣṭasiddhyupetam // GRhtCM_1.15:5 //
>
> कथं ब्रह्मपदं प्राप्नोति 
>   kathaṃ brahmapadaṃ prāpnoti //
>   GRhtCM_1.15:6 //
>
> यथा पुनरप्रथमं भवावासदुःखे संसारनिवासनतापत्रयात्मककष्टे न पततीत्यर्थः
>   
>    yathā punaraprathamaṃ bhavāvāsaduḥkhe
>   saṃsāranivāsanatāpatrayātmakakaṣṭe na patatītyarthaḥ // GRhtCM_1.15:7
>   //
>
> ज्ञानं प्राप्य ब्रह्मपदं प्राप्नोति 
>    jñānaṃ prāpya brahmapadaṃ
>   prāpnoti // GRhtCM_1.15:8 //
>
> **कथम् ऋते ज्ञानान्न मुक्तिरिति**  
>  
>   **katham ṛte jñānānna muktiriti** // GRhtCM_1.15:9 //
>
> अन्यच्च किं मोक्षतरोर्बीजं सम्यग्ज्ञानं क्रियासहितम् इति
>   प्रश्नोत्तररत्नमालायाम् 
>    anyacca kiṃ mokṣatarorbījaṃ samyagjñānaṃ
>   kriyāsahitam iti praśnottararatnamālāyām // GRhtCM_1.15:10 //